# Unable to verify the call on the mock in c#

Tags: c#, moq

I have a method call `SaveDocument()` in the class `DocumentStorageHandler`

```
DocumentManagementRequestModel docRequest=new DocumentManagementRequestModel
{
  Parameters = parameters,
  ProviderAlias = providerAlias
};
 _documentSaver.SaveDocument(docRequest);
```

and the `Parameter` class is as

```
public class DmuParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Object Value { get; set; }
    public string ParameterDirection { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm trying to write unit test for it, it gets failed with the "Expected invocation on the mock atleast once but was never performed".

```
_mockedDocumentSaver.Setup(d => d.SaveDocument(
            It.Is<DocumentManagementRequestModel>(
                d => d.Parameters.Exists(
                  p => p.Category == "category"
                   && p.Name == "FileLocation"
                   && p.Value.ToString() == "\\\\charon.cmiprog.com\\Devinet\\Documaker\\Api\\Temp\\1234567-00-00000-IdCardsPL.pdf"
                    && p.ParameterDirection == "Input"))));

_mockedDocumentSaver.Verify(c=>c.SaveDocument(It.Is<DocumentManagementRequestModel>(
            d=>d.Parameters.Exists(p=>
                    p.Category == "category"
                    && p.Name == "FileLocation"
                    && p.Value.ToString() == 
"\\\\charon.cmiprog.com\\Devinet\\Documaker\\Api\\Temp\\1234567-00-00000-IdCardsPL.pdf"
                    && p.ParameterDirection == "Input"
                ))),Times.AtLeastOnce);
```

Is it not the correct way I'm verfiying the invocation on mock. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

For additional Info, attached the screen shots.[image: The mock verification screen shot]
[image: In code]

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Was that method invoked?

Comment: how are you making the setup for the verify it self before calling it ? kindly include the code for setting up the mocks

Comment: @OlegI Yes I debugged it and the method gets invoked

Comment: @HanyHabib I included the setup for the mock. As shown in the pictures, the parameter gets added to the Pameters list as well

Comment: can we for simplicity try first   mock.Setup(d => d.SaveDocument(
            It.IsAny<DocumentManagementRequestModel>())  and on the verify to use the same to see the issue in the setup it self or in the definition

Comment: @HanyHabib Yes it works seemlessly

Comment: @HanyHabib I know it works that way, But I want to verify that the invocation happens on the request object where there will be a parameter named File Location and so on constraints

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've provided it looks like a string equality issue on Parameter.Value

The invocation break point screenshot has 'devinet' as lower case

[image]

In your verify break point screenshot 'DevInet' is mixed case

[image]

In the setup/verify expressions in the OP, it's 'Devinet'

Setup:

```
&& p.Value.ToString() == "\\\\charon.cmiprog.com\\Devinet\\Documaker\\Api\\Temp\\1234567-00-00000-IdCardsPL.pdf"
```

Verify:

```
&& p.Value.ToString() == "\\\\charon.cmiprog.com\\Devinet\\Documaker\\Api\\Temp\\1234567-00-00000-IdCardsPL.pdf"
```

I'd be running my eye over the casing. A CI equality condition may help with your debugging

```
&& p.Value.ToString().Equals("\\\\charon.cmiprog.com\\Devinet\\Documaker\\Api\\Temp\\1234567-00-00000-IdCardsPL.pdf", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```